# MPT Tangent Portfolio: Buck for the Bang Ratio

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio

[image]

The $R_{TP}$  is the tangent portfolio return, but I don't understand the step regarding $\frac{dV(R)}{dw_n}$, you apply this, and how come it get rids of the summation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get rid of the sum because you are computing the derivative of the variance with respect to one weight only (i.e. $\omega_n$)!

This implied that you take the derivative relatively to one single term of the sum, not all. You can basically compute $$\dfrac{dV(R)}{d\omega_n}$$ for all $n = [1, \cdots, N]$.

Regarding the calculation, and starting from the 3rd row of the derivation:

$$2 \omega_n Cov(R_n,R_n) + 2 Cov (R_n, \sum_{m \neq n} \omega_m R_m)$$

$$ = 2 Cov(R_n,\omega_n R_n) + 2 Cov (R_n, \sum_{m \neq n} \omega_m R_m)$$
(bilinearity of the covariance)
$$ = 2 Cov (R_n, \sum_{m} \omega_m R_m)$$
$$ = 2 Cov (R_n, \sum_{m} \omega_m R_m - (1 - \sum_{m} \omega_m) R_f)$$
(as the variance of a constant is zero. The constant I am referring to is $- (1 - \sum_{m} \omega_m) R_f$ since $R_f$ is deterministic. I have just added it in the covariance)
$$ = 2 Cov (R_n, R_{TP})$$

Comment: maybe you can explain the last two rows in greater detail how summing two covariance matrices is resulting in the covariance of tangent portfolio and security n

Comment: Sure, let me rewrite my answer in details

Comment: It wont let me edit out, but note that in your edits first elements of the first two lines should read $Cov(R_n, R_n)$ instead of $Cov(R_n, R_m)$.